# Subquery without temporary tables

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm having a problem which I wanted to solve with temporary tables, however, I discovered this is not really a good approach in Oracle.

I issue a select command from multiple tables and get Result1.  I then want to combine columns 2,3 into 1 column which contains the unique values from columns 2,3 e.g.

```
    Select distinct(col2) from Result1 
    UNION 
    Select distinct(col3) from Result1
    As Result2
```

I then want to use the values from Result2 in a subquery.  An easy way to do this last part to make the query above part of my Where clause as a subquery, but again I don't know how to reference Result1.  So what I want is:

```
      Select * from xyz where col in 
       (Select distinct(col2) from Result1 
        UNION 
        Select distinct(col3) from Result1)
```

What is the best way to combine the results of these queries in Oracle without a temp table?

Comment: Instead of `IN` Oracle devs prefer `EXIST` and `NOT EXIST` which are faster that `IN` because it does not actually return the data

Comment: Also `DISTINCT` inside each query is not needed.. as `UNION` will any give distinct result.. Some time.. optimiser itself will ignore the `DISTINCT` (forgives the bad query) .. Just an information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your query can be written as:

```
  Select *
  from xyz
  where col in (Select col2 from Result1 union all
                Select col3 from Result1
               )
```

The `in` automatically handles duplicates in this case.  This is better written as the following, using `with` for `result1`:

```
with result1 as (
      <your query here>
     )
select *
from xyz
where exists (select 1 from result1 r where xyz.col1 = r.col2 or xyz.col1 = r.col3);
```

Does that solve your problem?